# Changing a query from an integer parameter to a set

Tags: sql, parameters, dataset

I have the following code in a SQL query that I am trying to alter so that it will run for all `WhseID` values in a specific set, and not just a single `WhseID` set by the user:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_c_IMPriceChangeList]
        @WhseID varchar(3),
        @CompDate datetime
    as
    BEGIN
    Declare @whseKey int
    set @whseKey = (select whsekey from timwarehouse where whseid = @whseid)
```

I have tried altering it to:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_c_IMPriceChangeList_Catalog]
       @CompDate datetime
    as
    BEGIN
        Declare @whseKey int

        set @whseKey = (select whsekey from timwarehouse 
                        where whseid in ('001','010','011','012','013','014','015'))
```

But this gives me an error saying that a subquery following an equals sign cannot return more than one value. How can I make the change necessary?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: in your subquery set top 1. But that will bring you the top 1 which may not be the wanted one.

Comment: you'll somehow have to use a loop, but hard to help you with just that.

Comment: You can set ONLY one integer in your variable. Your subquery returns more than one

Comment: If this is for SQL Server, please note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Variable` is of type `INT` but your query is returning a `Table`, You cannot save a Table into a variable of Type `INT` Your need to create A Table Variable of and return that Table varible or Code in such a way the query only returns a single INT value. or you can simply Select the results and it will return the Result Set, Something like this..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_c_IMPriceChangeList]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT whsekey FROM timwarehouse 
    WHERE whseid IN ('001','010','011','012','013','014','015')   
END
```